# Provide iterable for single elements

Tags: python, iteration

I have a list that contains objects or another list of the same objects:

```
class OrderLine:
    pass 

lines = [OrderLine(), [OrderLine(), OrderLine()]]

def process_line(line):
    pass
```

when I query the list I need to do the following
from collections.abc import Iterable

```
index = 0
line = lines[index]
if isinstance(line, Iterable):
     for _line in line:
         process_line(_line) 
else:
     process_line(line)
```

My question is, how can I write the OrderLine class so that I don't have to check the type. The loop would enter one time if I get an OrderLine from the list, and more if I get an Iterable.
Like:

```
index = 0
line = lines[index]
for _line in line:
    process_line(_line)
```

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer.

Just write in the `OrderLine` class the following method:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return iter((self,))
```